# How to bypass the pre-flight checks when sending a tx with ethers?

Tags: erc-20, dapps, dapp-development, ethers.js

In my dapp, I have the following flow:

1. Create an empty transaction array.
2. Check if the ERC-20 allowance is sufficient and, if not, append a token approval tx to the array.
3. Append the token deposit transaction to the array.

In all cases, the array ends up having either one or two transactions inside. In the latter case, when the allowance is not sufficient, the second transaction cannot be sent because of this error thrown by ethers:

> "execution reverted: SafeERC20: low-level call failed"

Now, I know what causes this. I am not waiting for the approval transaction to go through, so the state of the blockchain assumes that the allowance is not sufficient and reverts when attempting to call the "transferFrom" function.

I want to bypass this check. Basically, I want to optimistically assume that the approval transaction will go through, and that nothing else will cause the deposit transaction to revert.

One way to do it is wrap the contract call in a try/ catch block, but that would mean I have to check the error string, so that when the error is different from the one quoted above, the user is alerted about it. Is there a more elegant way to do this in ethers? Maybe there is an option that I can turn on and disable the "would this transaction revert" check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after posting the question, thanks to this [comment](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/903#issuecomment-648398488) left by ricmoo:

> Are you setting a gasLimit? If there is no gasLimit set, ethers will use estimateGas, which can throw a CALL_EXCEPTION if the call would fail, which in this case it would.

If we don't provide a hardcoded "gasLimit", ethers tries to estimate the gas cost by itself. But when the ERC-20 allowance is not sufficient (as in my case), the transaction reverts, as it should.

Therefore, the solution is to pass a "gasLimit" to the contract call. Not great, not terrible.